# UPS disposal

Tags: ups

What do I need to do to get rid of my old UPS?  The battery no longer works, and the unit is probably completely hosed at this point, as the equipment on it suffers from the occasional complete reboot.  So, I won't give it to someone or donate it, because it's just a bad piece of hardware, and over five years old.

So, how can I dispose of this thing?  I'm in Southern California, which I think might be relevant because disposal programs probably vary based on locale.

EDIT in response to responses:  Will battery recycling places and mechanic's garages recycle just the battery, or the entire unit as well?  Isn't there other circuitry or environmental nastiness in this thing, or is it just the battery I need to be concerned with?

Comment: A simple Google search for battery recyclers in your area should get you what you want. Just give it to them!

Comment: You could try replacing the battery.

Comment: It's actually far more convenient at this point to just replace the UPS.  This is a really old unit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or you could trade it in.  I know some UPS manufacturers will take trade-ins - APC in particular (even a UPS from another manufacturer):

[APC Trade-UPS](http://buy.apc.com/commerce/storefronts/tradeups/tradein.aspx)

Comment: +1. The APC Trade-UPS program is great if you plan to get another UPS anyway. Looks like mmr is trying to do that.

Comment: yep, this is the right call.

Answer (score 2):

Take it to a car garage. They deal with battery disposal. Don't let them charge you to take it. It's worth money to recycle.

Answer (score 1):

You could try asking the people who you will be buying the new UPS from if they can take the old one back for recycling (you are buying a replacement aren't you?). If the reseller doesn't take it back, the manufacturer might.

Answer (score 0):

Many manufacturers will take back the batteries when you buy a replacement, like the manufacturers of toner cartridges do.

The only problem here though is the weight of the battery making it too expensive to post (and you shouldn't be sending that sort o chemical filled boxes that UPS batteries are in the post anyway) but you might find they have a local affiliate who will take them as they sell you a new battery.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, along with other answers, to recycle the battery with the hazardous materials recycling depot in your area. Being CA, they should have that info on local gov websites (they do here in FL). Then take the rest of it to an electronics recycling depot. Some places will do both at the same depot.

If you take it someplace which recycles both, either take the battery out and give them each separately, or make it *very* clear that the UPS has an SLA battery inside. You could be fined for not telling them.

Answer (score 0):

you can narrow a facility down by county here:

http://www.ciwmb.ca.gov/Electronics/Collection/RecyclerSearch.aspx

I'm sure you'll be able to find a facility that will recycle everything in the UPS (case, battery, internal electronics, etc).

If you take it to a mechanic, they would probably get the battery recycled properly, and the case if it's metal, but the rest would probably end up in a dumpster, then landfill.

Answer (score 0):

I went to my County's website, they have a program where they take all the electronic and chemical stuff every other week in different Home Depots. I save all my stuff and make a trip about once a year.